# How to use multi scss in Electron-Vue Project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, electron-vue

I want to use multi scss Files in Electron-Vue and i am able to use single scss file in Electron-vue with the help of this solution [By adding this in webpack.renderer.js](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue/issues/699#issuecomment-428444374) .

Note: Using Bootstrap

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've installed Bootstrap and sass loader in Vue Projekt, you can also leave bootstrap loader and put bootstrap folder inside css folder or you can also use Bootstrap like do as your requirements, but remember Sass Loader is must do be loaded.

1. Create a master.scss
2. import all your other scss Files like this in master.scss --->  @import 'filename';
3. In app.vue add this in script section --->
   import 'path_to_your_master_file/master.scss'

Thats it,
Hope it will help others.